# Swift Sandbox User In app Purchases Loop

Tags: swift, in-app-purchase

Im using a sandbox user to test In app Purchases in my app, it was working well a few days ago, but today, when im testing In app Purchase I need to sign in, my user and password are correct, and then I click buy and then nothing happens, and the sign in view appears again, and the process get repeated. I have sign out of any Apple ID in my physical iPhone, as recommended.

Comment: Version you are running on your iPhone?

Comment: The version of my iPhone is 11.0

Answer (score 1):

Do the following thing to resolve your problem:

1. Remove your personal `Apple ID` from `Settings`.
2. Crash the app.
3. Sign In to iTunes Store using `Sandbox ID`.
4. Launch the app and try to buy again.

I have tested this because I was facing the same issue. Let me know if problem still persists.

P.S. Give a restart also in case if it doesn't works.

Comment: thanks for your response, The loop has gone, but the purchase fails.

Comment: @GerarTorres Can you please check `error` while debugging?